# Micronaut Kotlin tests not working when running from Intellij

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, micronaut

I am creating a simple todo application using Micronaut and Kotlin. Here is my repository.
https://github.com/faskan/todo-micronaut-kotlin

Note that this is a code generated by [micronaut launch](https://micronaut.io/launch/) and I haven't made any changes in it. Following the [documentation](https://docs.micronaut.io/3.0.0-M2/guide/index.html#ideaSetup), I have enabled annotation processors and was expecting my tests to run in Intellij **but it doesn't.** I have this problem only with Kotlin, with Java as language the tests works fine.
A screenshot of my intellij settings.
[Screenshot of Intellij settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tLtc.png)

I have tried adding `dagger-compiler` annotation processor in to my maven execution configuration. But no help. Appreciate any help to find what the problem is.

Stacktrace:

```
org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluationException: Failed to evaluate condition [io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.MicronautJunit5Extension]: @MicronautTest used on test but no bean definition for the test present. This error indicates a misconfigured build or IDE. Please add the 'micronaut-inject-java' annotation processor to your test processor path (for Java this is the testAnnotationProcessor scope, for Kotlin kaptTest and for Groovy testCompile). See the documentation for reference: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluator.evaluationException(ConditionEvaluator.java:81)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluator.evaluate(ConditionEvaluator.java:69)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluator.lambda$evaluate$0(ConditionEvaluator.java:55)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.tryAdvance(StreamSpliterators.java:302)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.tryAdvance(Streams.java:723)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.tryAdvance(Streams.java:720)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluator.evaluate(ConditionEvaluator.java:57)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.shouldBeSkipped(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.shouldBeSkipped(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$checkWhetherSkipped$2(NodeTestTask.java:119)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.checkWhetherSkipped(NodeTestTask.java:119)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:81)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestInstantiationException: @MicronautTest used on test but no bean definition for the test present. This error indicates a misconfigured build or IDE. Please add the 'micronaut-inject-java' annotation processor to your test processor path (for Java this is the testAnnotationProcessor scope, for Kotlin kaptTest and for Groovy testCompile). See the documentation for reference: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.MicronautJunit5Extension.evaluateExecutionCondition(MicronautJunit5Extension.java:145)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluator.evaluate(ConditionEvaluator.java:64)
    ... 54 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IntelliJ compiler doesn't allow running annotation processors for Kotlin with KAPT so you have to delegate to Gradle or Maven for the build

We have reported this many times to JetBrains but unfortunately they don't seem interested in improving the user experience for Kotlin users that use KAPT

Comment: Thank you @Graeme Rocher. That explains, I will delegate it to maven

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.micronaut.io/3.0.0-M2/guide/index.html#ideaSetup) say to add `micronaut-core` dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

dependency to project and `micronaut-inject-java`:

```
<annotationProcessorPaths>
    <path>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
    </path>
</annotationProcessorPaths>
```

to annotation processor path.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't work even after adding micronaut-core dependency. And the micronaut-inject-java dependency, I had it initially as well but commented it to try out something. Now I have enabled it again, but no luck. Sorry I couldn't find where exactly the doc says to add micronaut core dependency.